# Error al mostrar una cadena de caracteres en c

Tags: c, codeblocks

debo determinar el maximo de importe pagado y mostrar los datos del cliente que pago el importe, todos los resultados se muestran correctamente menos las cadenas de caracteres, salen vacias y no encuentro el error

```
void maximo( struct cliente c[]){

int max=0;
char nombremax[50];
int edadmax;
int dnimax;
char domimax[50];
for (int i=0;i<1;i++){
    if (c[i].importe>max){
        max=c[i].importe;
        strcpy(c[i].nombre,nombremax);
        edadmax=c[i].edad;
        dnimax=c[i].dni;
        strcpy(c[i].domicilio,domimax);

    }
}
printf ("-------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("el cliente que mas abono es: %s con %d\n",nombremax,max);
printf("D.N.I.: %d\n",dnimax);
printf("Edad: %d\n",edadmax);
printf("Domicilio: %s\n",domimax);

return;
}
```

Esta es la funcion que realice para el mismo, ingresando los datos de nombre y domicilio (los que me tiran error por medio de un:

```
printf("Escriba el nombre del cliente %d: ",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(c[i].nombre,50,stdin);
```

Todo esto realizado dentro de un for para ir recorriendo el registro c[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia `strcpy(c[i].nombre,nombremax);` por `strcpy(nombremax,c[i].nombre);`
El primer argumento de la función es el destino y el segundo el origen.